# How can I add an exception to the Content Security Policy in Firefox 56?

Tags: firefox, browser, internet-security

I am using Firefox 56 because it is the last version that still allows me to use my add-ons.

Today Twitter has changed something in their coding, so that the videos posted on Twitter stopped playing in the browser. While trying to play a video I get a message: `The media could not be played` In the Web Console I see an error message, like: `Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at blob:https://twitter.com/5970af6d-d6ea-43e1-9bd6-c9d33f08d0a6 (“default-src https://twitter.com”)`

If I completely disable the browser's Content Security Policy, by setting "**security.csp.enable**" to "**false**", then the videos play normally, as they used to be. Also the videos play normally in Firefox 65 without any tweaks.

I do not want to completely disable the Content Security Policy in my browser as this would pose a security risk.

**Is there any way to add an exception to the Content Security Policy in Firefox 56?**

=======================================================

**Update:**

Twitter sends the following response header:

```
content-security-policy: connect-src 'self' blob: https://*.giphy.com https://*.pscp.tv https://*.video.pscp.tv https://*.twimg.com https://api.twitter.com https://caps.twitter.com https://media.riffsy.com https://pay.twitter.com https://sentry.io https://ton.twitter.com https://twitter.com https://upload.twitter.com https://www.google-analytics.com https://vmap.snappytv.com https://vmapstage.snappytv.com https://vmaprel.snappytv.com https://vmap.grabyo.com https://mdhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://mpdhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://mmdhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://smdhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://smpdhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://smmdhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://rmdhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://rmpdhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://rmmdhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://dwo3ckksxlb0v.cloudfront.net ; default-src 'self'; form-action 'self' https://twitter.com https://*.twitter.com; font-src 'self' https://*.twimg.com; frame-src 'self' https://twitter.com https://mobile.twitter.com https://pay.twitter.com https://cards-frame.twitter.com ; img-src 'self' blob: data: https://*.cdn.twitter.com https://ton.twitter.com https://*.twimg.com https://www.google-analytics.com https://www.periscope.tv https://www.pscp.tv https://media.riffsy.com https://*.giphy.com https://*.pscp.tv; manifest-src 'self'; media-src 'self' blob: https://twitter.com https://*.twimg.com https://*.vine.co https://*.pscp.tv https://*.video.pscp.tv https://*.giphy.com https://media.riffsy.com https://mdhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://mpdhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://mmdhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://smdhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://smpdhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://smmdhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://rmdhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://rmpdhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://rmmdhdsnappytv-vh.akamaihd.net https://dwo3ckksxlb0v.cloudfront.net; object-src 'none'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://*.twimg.com   https://www.google-analytics.com https://twitter.com  'nonce-NWNhMmQ5ZjQtYTgwZS00YjVjLTkyODgtNDEzMDMwYWIyOWU2'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://*.twimg.com; worker-src 'self' blob:; report-uri https://twitter.com/i/csp_report?a=O5RXE%3D%3D%3D&ro=false
```

**Is there any way to remove (filter out) the blob entries from it when a page is loading?**

Comment: Not the answer you're looking for, but there have been a lot of critical security updates (as well as changes to how CSPs are handled) between FF 56 and 70, so I'd advise getting those add-ons rewritten or find alternatives so you can update.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a browser extension to override the CSP header for that website:
https://bewisse.com/modheader/

Add a URL Pattern filter for twitter's website and a Response Header of 'content-security-policy' with some lax policy, such as "default-src *", and see if that works. It sounds like your browser isn't handling policies properly so I'm not 100% sure how it will handle this.

Comment: Only the pro edition which you have to pay for will do that. See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1802189 for a requests to get a simple solution again.